# Can't get thread to start in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multithreading

I am trying to start a thread in a form for a function that takes about 5 seconds to run so I can keep the UI from locking up.  I have the following code below, but it fails when it hits "thread1.start."  When I watch it though a debugger it just goes strait to "End Sub" and it does not go to the getSecurityStuff() method that I am expecting it to go to.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class frmAddAssets

    Private theDict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = Nothing


    Private Sub frmAddAssets_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub cmbTickerEntry_Leave(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbTickerEntry.Leave

        Dim thread1 As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf getSecurityStuff))

        thread1.Start()

    End Sub

    Public Sub getSecurityStuff()

        Dim getData As New clsSecurityView(cmbTickerEntry.Text())

        Try
            theDict = getData.getStockData()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try

        filldata()

    End Sub

    Private Sub filldata()

        Dim list As New List(Of String)(theDict.Keys)

        txtTicker.Text = cmbTickerEntry.Text.ToString()

        For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In theDict

            Select Case True
                Case kvp.Key = "Name"
                    txtSecurityName.Text = kvp.Value.ToString()
                Case kvp.Key = "Price"
                    txtPrice.Text = kvp.Value.ToString()
                Case kvp.Key = "Market Capitalization"
                    txtMarketCap.Text = kvp.Value.ToString()
                Case kvp.Key = "Dividend Yield"
                    txtDivYield.Text = kvp.Value.ToString()
                Case kvp.Key = "PE Ratio"
                    txtPERatio.Text = kvp.Value.ToString()
                Case kvp.Key = "EPS"
                    txtEPS.Text = kvp.Value.ToString()
            End Select

        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Code tip: don't initialize anything to `Nothing`, it's pointless.

Comment: Your debugger goes to "End Sub" because that's the next line. Put a breakpoint at the beginning of "getSecurityStuff" to debug the new thread.

Comment: In fact, [here's your code just generally cleaned up](http://codepad.org/z9QJjL3P).

Comment: Thanks for the re-write.  I like how compact that is compared to mine.

Comment: @minitech Just out of curiosity using your method of `Call New Thread(AddressOf GetSecurityStuff) With {.IsBackground = True}.Start()` would it be possible to add parameters to `AddressOf GetSecurityStuff(param, param2)`?  I've been looking for a good way to do this, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Thanks!

Comment: @LanceCollins: A delegate that `New Thread` accepts is `ParameterizedThreadStart`, which can take a single `Object` argument. This will partially remove the need for `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` - just make sure you cast it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...When I watch it though a debugger it just goes strait to "End
>   Sub"...

Please note that `thread1.Start()` won't block the current thread.

Setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `False` won't do anything, but ignore the exception(s) that's throwen, when you access the properties of a control owned by the UI thread - which also is your problem:

- You create a new thread
- The new thread calls `getSecurityStuff`
- You try to declare a new `clsSecurityView`, with `cmbTickerEntry.Text` as parameter.
- EXCEPTION - you try to access a control owned by the UI thread, while being on another thread!
- No exception shows up, because you've set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `False`

Same deal with `fillData`... trying to access controls outside the UI thread.

**Solution:** Use `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` to execute code that should read/modify properties on controls owned by the UI thread.

Comment: Good advice, but I think the exception only occurs in debugging, to make sure that this kind of mistake isn't made. Setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `False` should prevent the exceptions and continue with the code... I think the issue might be elsewhere.

Comment: minitech, Setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `False` will not *prevent* the exceptions, it will *ignore* them, and therefore fail silent.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls.aspx "while the application is being debugged."

Comment: minitech, Who says he's not testing in debugging mode? I'm not sure why you find it relevant that the value of `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` only counts in debug mode, when `Lance Collins` haven't said anything about how he runs the app.

Comment: Try it: Just open up a new Windows Forms application and paste [this](http://codepad.org/gistNxtH) in. Then uncomment the line. It works - the `InvalidOperationException` is an attempt to prevent synchronization errors. What I'm saying is that it's probably not the source of the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Dim action as New Action(AddressOf getSecurityStuff)
action.BeginInvoke(Nothing, Nothing)
```

Comment: And that will help how? It's the same thing, except using a thread from the thread pool.

Comment: @minitech OP posted that _fails when it hits "thread1.start."_ Hence my suggestion was trying different syntax might help.